# How to consume External Services in DDD

Tags: api, domain-driven-design

I have a project in DDD and I would like to know in which layer I have to code a Service to consume an external service. In this case the external service is about information (especifically payment slips) to show in the Front-End.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The question is a bit vage, but my guess is that you have a bounded context and you even have an UI for this bounded context. Now you would like to show some data from another (external)BC in the UI of your BC. 
Before creating an application service for that, ask yourself: what should the user do with this information? Does it help to solve some business problem of your BC? Does the user take different actions inside your BC depending on the payment slip data that he or she sees? If so, then you probably need to model those busines rules explicitly inside the domain model of your BC, create some sort of relationship to the other BC and agree on a contract to get the data to satisfy your invariants. 
If you just need a shortcut/convienience for the user in the UI then try to push this feature to the UI level, maybe a simple link to the other context is enough... 
Reaching out to external BCs should not be done careless, since every external dependency makes your BC less independent and valuable on its own. First try to clarify the communication to the other context using one of the strategic design patterns like anti-corruption-layer, customer-supplier, conformist etc. After this analysis it should be easier to determine in which layer an how you would put the logic for this external call.